# Please provide the possibility to retract a flag

Tags: feature-request, flags

You can delete a question you posted, you can delete a comment you posted, it's absolutely ridiculous that you cannot undo flagging a comment if you flagged it by mistake.

Please implement this feature.

Comment: If your flag is wrong it will be declined and life will go on. What is the harm that is caused by you not retracting your flag?

Comment: Well, the argument can be made that retracting a flag saves moderators' time as they try to figure out what the flag was about. I don't see what harm would be caused by *allowing* retraction.